# iOS position:fixed and scrolling

Tags: javascript, ios, css, css-position

we try to implement an action button like in GMail to add new content. 
It has therefore to be fixed during scroll.

Simple as that, here's the HTML:

```
<div class="addButton actionButton" onclick="">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus"></i>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.addButton
    {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 1em;
        right: 1.5em;
        z-index: 10;
        background-color: #00aa00;
    }
```

On Android and browser it works like a charm, in iOS it does not. 
Maybe to add the we got as slideview and one of the parent divs got a position:relative.

Everytime we scroll, the button stays on its place. When we use the next slide and slide back, the button is correct. It seems that iOS does not update the viewport. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wqqragmm/1/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it seems like whenever I do the "simulation" inside an iOS device i get this little scrollbar on x axis. And when you scroll I guess it has some kind of an impact on "position: fixed" elements. This always solves all my problems with "position: fixed" elements inside iOS devices.
`html{overflow-x: hidden} body{overflow-x: hidden}`.